# How to run a container infrequently but with high performance in Azure

Tags: azure, containers

I have some workload which needs to be run a few times per week. It requires some heavy computational work and runs about one hour (with 16 cores and 32gb memory). It is possible to run it in a container.

Azure offers many different possibilities to run containers. (I have no knowledge of most of the Azure services, so my conclusions might be wrong.) Firstly, I thought Azure Container Instances is perfect for this scenario, but it only offers containers with up to 4 vCPU and 16gb memory. There is no need for orchestration with a single container, so Azure Kubernetes Service and Azure Service Fabric come with too much overhead. Similarly, Azure Batch also offers computational clusters which are not needed for a single workload.

Which Azure service is the best fit for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a "best fit" question is likely to be closed.  Anyways, here's a suggestion.

Don't dismiss AKS.  You can easily create a 1 node cluster using a VM that fits your required configuration.  Using the standard SLA, you don't pay for the master node and you can [stop your cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/start-stop-cluster) after each run and stop being charged.  No need to bother about orchestration, see this as a VM that has everything to run your container that you'll use like an ACI.

Comment: Thanks for answering even if this question will be closed. This topic is just difficult for me to approach without having detailed knowledge of each Azure Service.